# How do I restore iOS safari history/determine when it was cleared?

Tags: ios

I need to either: restore a deleted iOS Safari history; or,
find the date/time that the Safari history file was cleared.  Can anyone direct me to simple directions to do either/both of these tasks?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a simple way to do this since the system doesn't record an audit log of changes to safari that would allow you to easily detect the when and more importantly the what changed from moment to moment.

Theoretically, the file system would have a last modified date (that can easily be changed) to indicate the last time the file was saved - but you would either need some forensics skills to build up a history and a snapshot of the filesystem going back in time - like Time Machine might provide you.

Since Time Machine doesn't exist on iOS - your best bet is to restore the entire phone from your backups and test to see if the history is correct. This is similar to building a new house because you want a new cabinet drawer in one bathroom, but there just isn't an interface (at least built by Apple) to automate what you ask.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this can be done.

Comment: He is asking for iOS' Safari.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  I am seeking advice for an iphone 4 on ios 5.1.1.  I have spoken to AT&T/Apple who indicated that there is 'a way to do what I'm seeking' however, they both recommended that I find out how via a 3rd party provider of such info!  $600 for a phone and $175 per month for service, and they send me elsewhere to find answers to questions they recognize do have answers, but which, apparently, are too challenging for them to communicate to me directly.

Comment: AT&T should have informed you of the scope of support. Apple supports iOS and first line support for hardware. (i.e. everything except billing and data/call features where you should call the carrier first for support). You should be rightly upset that they didn't explain how the support is broken down between the carrier and manufacturer and offer to assist you in finding the Apple support by phone, web or in person.